# Multi-select dropdown overlay/hover over table rows (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to create a table where one of the items in the table () contains a dropdown for multiple selects. For this I use mobius1-selectr.

Whenever I use the dropdown, it doesn't hover over the rest of the table items, but stays within the table. After which I have to scroll down to see the entire dropdown menu.

See screenshot:
[image]

Hereby a piece of the code, where I try to test this out.

```
<div class=" table-responsive">
            <table class=" table align-items-center table-flush">
                <thead class=" thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>User</th>

                    <th>Teams</th>

                    <th>Roles</th>

                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="table-user">
                        <img class=" avatar rounded-circle mr-3" src="assets/img/theme/team-1.jpg"/>
                        <b> Test User </b>
                    </td>

                    <td style="z-index: 1020">
                        <select class="form-control" data-toggle="select" id="selectr-multiple" style="z-index: 1020; position: absolute">
                            <option value="test1"> Test 1 </option>
                            <option value="test2"> Test 2 </option>
                            <option value="test3"> Test 3 </option>
                            <option value="test4"> Test 4 </option>
                            <option value="test5"> Test 5 </option>
                            <option value="test6"> Modals </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <a class=" font-weight-bold" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            Link to Profile
                        </a>
                    </td>

                    <td class=" table-actions">
                        <a
                                class="table-action"
                                tooltip="Edit product"
                                placement="top"
                                href="javascript:void(0)"
                        >
                            <i class=" fas fa-user-edit"> </i>
                        </a>

                        <a
                                class=" table-action table-action-delete"
                                tooltip="Delete product"
                                placement="top"
                                href="javascript:void(0)"
                        >
                            <i class=" fas fa-trash"> </i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

```
.table-responsive {
  @each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
    $next: breakpoint-next($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($next, $grid-breakpoints);

    &#{$infix} {
      @include media-breakpoint-down($breakpoint) {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;


        > .table-bordered {
          border: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I create this in a way that it drops over the table and (eventual) rows below? As I am not really a HTML/CSS expert, some help and guidance would really be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share reproducible example here with css.

Comment: It looks like you have some overflow: hidden on your table. If you can provide working exampe it can help to guide you.

Comment: @VikasJadhav please find the updated HTML and CSS (for table-responsive)

Comment: @vv01 try removing overflow-x: auto; from table css

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, now I need to find out how to make sure that mobius1-selectr doesn't resize based on selection. Thanks